# Component that accepts either of two types and conditional renders something depending on the type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-generics, react-typescript

The two types to choose between are `A` and `B`:

```
interface Base {
    base: string;
}
interface BaseWithA extends Base {
    a: string;
}
interface BaseWithB extends Base {
    b: string;
}
```

Pseudocode for the goal:

```
const Foo = (props:  `either type BaseWithA or BaseWithB`  ) => {
    if (props instanceof BaseWithA) {
        return props.a;
    }
    return props.b;  // must be BaseWithB
}
```

Explanation:

So if the generic type `T` is `BaseWithA`, we know we can access `props.a`.

In contrast, if the generic type `T` is `BaseWithB`, we know we can access `props.b`.

---

This is my attempt:

```
const Foo = <T extends Base>(props: T) => {
    if (T instanceof BaseWithA) {    <------ ERROR: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
        return props.a;
    }
    return props.b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to implement such a function:

```
const isBaseWithA = (props: Base): props is BaseWithA => {
  return (props as BaseWithA).a !== undefined
}
```

you can then use the function like this:

```
 if (isBaseWithA(props)) {
    return props.a;
  }
```

But it is more a workaround, because if an object is of type `BaseWithA`, and has an undefined `a` props, then you can't differenciate.

If you want to use the `instanceof` keyword, you have to work rather with classes, like this:

```
class A implements BaseWithA {
  a = "";
  base = "";
}
```

You can then use the following snippet:

```
if (props instanceof A) {
    return props.a
  }
```

Comment: Indeed, it is a solution, but can you really not do it with less code? Is a function really necessary?

Comment: I have updated with a shorter version, indeed